# Insert multiple records at once

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a group of radio buttons returning the following hash:

```
{"1"=>"1", "3"=>"2"}
```

The key represents the event_id and the value represents the regoption_id. I need to insert these to the subscriptions table preferably all at once. 
I tried the following:

```
params[:children].each do |child|    
  Subscription.create({:event_id => child[0], :regoption_id => child[1]}).save
end
```

This ends up saving just **one** radio group, not all in the hash. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Just fyi, the `create` method performs `save` on it's own.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Problem remains however ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a gem called [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) that will insert multiple records efficiently.  It works with many popular DB backends, and will just do the right thing with most of them.  This does exactly what you want: it accepts an array of object instances, or an array-of-hashes-of-values, and inserts them into a table in a single statement.

Here's a usage example right from the gem documentation:

```
books = []
10.times do |i| 
  books << Book.new(:name => "book #{i}")
end
Book.import books
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work with my setup. It still inserts only the last record

Comment: I decided to go for the 'raw sql' solution and it works fine. No validation/callbacks possible obviously, but that is fine in this case.